# Does the parent image of a Docker image get implicitly pulled from its repository if you run an already-built docker image?

Tags: docker, containers

Does the parent image of a docker image, the image source that follows after "FROM" in your Dockerfile, also need to be pulled again if you pull and run that custom docker image which is already built and uploaded? Or is the parent image already embedded in the child docker image?

I am NOT talking about docker build step here, I am talking about just pulling the built image and running it in docker engine.

Edit: NOT talking about pulling manually, too. Just asking if the docker engine automatically pulls.

Edit: I believe the parent image is embedded. But some layer seems to be pulling from its parent image's repository in my test. Note that this is not conclusive. It may well be that the Dockerfile of the parent image is doing something that requires connection to its own repository.

Comment: Docker doesn't pull parent layers again while running the image. This may help : https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/a-beginners-guide-to-understanding-and-building-docker-images/

Comment: @MehdiFathi, thanks. I have already looked at it. Although that page contains basic information about Docker, it doesn't say whether the parent images have been implicitly and internally pulled by the docker engine or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

A docker image can have multiple layers. If some images of the layers are not distributable, these layers won't be in your registry and they have to be pulled from their **original location** such as Windows base image from Microsoft Container Registry, etc...

If you want all base layers images to be pulled from your own registry, you have to configure it using

```
{
   "allow-nondistributable-artifacts": ["myregistrydomain.com:5000"]
}
```

as per [this article](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) from docker.
Then when you build and push your image to that registry, it will include all base images - even non-distributable ones.

Answer (score 0):

It is part of the image you built so you don't need to pull it again in order to run the container using the built image